# How is it true that for large $t$, $(1+O(1/t))e^{-2\ln t O(1/t)}=1+O(\ln t/t)$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

The title pretty much says it all. At some point in large time analysis, the following claim popped out but I don't see how it is true: For sufficiently large $t>0$,

$$
\frac{2\ln t}{t}(1+O(1/t))e^{-2(\ln t) O(1/t)}=\frac{2\ln t}{t}(1+O((\ln t)/t))
$$

It'd be nice if someone could explain what's going on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just write, as $t \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
(1+O(1/t))e^{-2\ln t \, O(1/t)}&=(1+O(1/t))e^{ O((\ln t)/t)}
\\\\&=(1+O(1/t))(1+O((\ln t)/t))
\\\\&=1+O((\ln t)/t)+O(1/t)+O((\ln t)/t^2)
\\\\&=1+O((\ln t)/t)
\end{align}
$$
as announced.